# Handling HTTP POST request/response

Tags: c++, sockets, http, unix

I've been trying to send HTTP POST Request to facebook without success i get this response from the server :

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Date:
>   Sat, 10 Dec 2016 21:28:17 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 2959

Facebook | Error

> Sorry, something went wrong We're working on it and we'll get it fixed
>   as soon as we can

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s, error;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;


        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(s <0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 01: creating socket failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton("31.13.90.36",&addr.sin_addr);

    error = connect(s,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    if(error!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Error 02: conecting to server failed!\n";
        close(s);
        return 1;
    }

     const int msgSize = 1042;
     char msg[] = "POST /login.php?login_attempt=1 \r\n"
                     "HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                     "HOST: facebook.com\r\n\r\n"
                     "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                     "Content-Length: 41\r\n"
                     "email=lel@gmail.com&pass=test123&submit=1\r\n" ;







     char answ[1042];

    //cin.getline(&msg[0],256);

    send(s,msg,strlen(msg),0);


    ssize_t len;
    while((len = recv(s, msg, strlen(msg), 0)) > 0)
    {
        cout.write(msg, len);

        std::cout << std::flush;
    }
    if(len < 0)
    {
        cout << "error";
    }
    close(s);  

}
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several errors in your message. This is what you send according to your code:

```
1  POST /login.php?login_attempt=1 \r\n
2  HTTP/1.1\r\n 
3  HOST: facebook.com\r\n\r\n
4  Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
5  Content-Length: 41\r\n
6  email=lel@gmail.com&pass=test123&submit=1\r\n
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
1  POST /login.php?login_attempt=1 HTTP/1.1\r\n
2  HOST: facebook.com\r\n
3  Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
4  Content-Length: 41\r\n
5  \r\n
6  email=lel@gmail.com&pass=test123&submit=1
```

In detail:

- Line 1 and 2 should be a single line, i.e. "method path HTTP-version"
- Line 3 should not contain multiple `\r\n`
- instead the empty line `\r\n` should be after all HTTP headers (new line 5)
- the body in line 6 should contain only the data covered by the content-length. The 41 bytes you set there don't include the `\r\n` you send

Apart from that you don't properly parse the response and instead expect the server to close the connection once the response is done. Since you are using `HTTP/1.1` you implicitly use persistent connections (HTTP keep-alive) so the server might actually wait for more requests within the same TCP connection and not close the connection immediately.

I really recommend that you study the [standard of HTTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) instead of guessing how the protocol might work.

Comment: I didn't guess i used Live HTTP headers app by the way when i test the new code I get HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
I think this mean link changed how can i follow the link? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AmineDjenaihi: yes, this means follow the link given in the Location header. And this is covered by the RFC. And I have no idea what you've seen with Live HTTP headers but you got several line breaks wrong: you've added three which don't belong there and removed one where it belongs. Apart from that a browser adds many more headers so I'm pretty sure you did not copy the original request from the browser but guessed from what you saw there.

Comment: @AmineDjenaihi: Again, please [read  the HTTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).  301 is a redirect response. It includes a `Location` header for the new URL.  Repeat your same request to the new URL.

Comment: Okay got it, Thanks for your time guys!